# How to Render Select Field in Flask it gives error two many values to unpack?

Tags: python, flask

**APP CODE**:for making form

```
branch_choices = [('CSE','CSE'),('ECE','ECE'),('MEC','MEC'),('CIVIL','CIVIL')]
year_choices = [('1st','1st'),('2nd','2nd'),('3rd','3rd'),('4th','4th')]

class CSIForm(Form):
    branch = SelectField('Branch',choices=branch_choices, validators=[Required()])
    year = SelectField('Year',choices=year_choices, validators=[Required()])

def index():
    form=CSIForm()
    return render_template('form.html',form=form)
```

**HTML CODE**:for rendering code into html

```
{{ form.branch.label }}
{{ form.branch() }}

{{ form.year.label }}
{{ form.year() }}
```

Answer (score 1):

`choices` needs to be a list of tuples, not a list of strings.

Refer to the documentation: http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.SelectField

Your code could be updated as such:

```
class CSIForm(Form):
    branch_choices = [('CSE','CSE'),('ECE','ECE'),('MEC','MEC'),('CIVIL','CIVIL')]
    year_choices = [('1st','1st'),('2nd','2nd'),('3rd','3rd'),('4th','4th')]
    branch = SelectField('Branch',choices=branch_choices, validators=[Required()])
    year = SelectField('Year',choices=year_choices, validators=[Required()])
```

Answer (score 0):

The code matthewh provided is correct— if you're not running in debug mode and haven't restarting the application you might not be seeing your changes.

Here is a complete application, working with the code matthewh provided:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import SelectField
from wtforms.validators import Required


branch_choices = [('CSE','CSE'),('ECE','ECE'),('MEC','MEC'),('CIVIL','CIVIL')]
year_choices = [('1st','1st'),('2nd','2nd'),('3rd','3rd'),('4th','4th')]

class CSIForm(Form):
    branch = SelectField('Branch',choices=branch_choices, validators=[Required()])
    year = SelectField('Year',choices=year_choices, validators=[Required()])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "Moo."

@app.route('/')
def index():
    form=CSIForm()
    return render_template('form.html',form=form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The source code of the rendered page is:

```
<label for="branch">Branch</label>
<select id="branch" name="branch"><option value="CSE">CSE</option><option value="ECE">ECE</option><option value="MEC">MEC</option><option value="CIVIL">CIVIL</option></select>

<label for="year">Year</label>
<select id="year" name="year"><option value="1st">1st</option><option value="2nd">2nd</option><option value="3rd">3rd</option><option value="4th">4th</option></select>
```